# link not working in image section

Tags: images, links

Hi in my site [paintint](https://paintint.com) there is an interior designer section under slider whenever I put a link to that image like this [link](https://paintint.com/interior-painting/) it adds `/v` after any link automatically:

```
https://paintint.com/interior-painting/v
```

Why?

Comment: Is the slider a plugin or custom code? Without more information, there is no way to answer this question.

Comment: nothing I'm using paint theme by wedesign them and WpBakery page builder